# How to fix horizontal lines on screen appearing on my laptop screen

Tags: windows-7, display, toshiba-laptop

I have a Toshiba Satellite A105-S4334. The screen shows horizontal lines. When connected to an external monitor, the display is normal with no lines.

I tried replacing the screen and cables, but the problem remains.

Windows 7 with all current drivers.

Lines are mostly blue, red and yellow. More or less like this one:

[image: example]

Comment: If you change the *Screen Resolution*, are the lines present at all usable choices? If so, it seems like a hardware issue.

Comment: Bad panel or bad cable between laptop and panel. If you slowly move the lid, do the lines change?

Comment: I replaced the screen and cables but the lines are still there. Someone suggested to do a Cleaning Reballing and that will fix things for me.

Comment: Please describe the lines (black, white, specific colors)?  Do they go edge to edge?  Are they visible against a black background?  Are the line colors affected by the color or brightness of the screen content they pass through?  What is their location?  Can you post a link to a picture?  At what point do they become visible (power-on, logo screen, boot)?

Comment: Lines are mostly blue, red and yellow. More or less like this one https://i.ytimg.com/vi/GfSUlqecZaM/hqdefault.jpg

Comment: This doesn't make a lot of sense.  These symptoms are typically caused by problems with the local screen interface or connectors within the screen assembly.  If you replaced the screen and cables with new parts, that should have fixed it.  I suspect that solving this will require hands-on diagnostics and repair, and that this isn't a problem Super User could be very effective at helping with.

Comment: Thank you fixer1234. I guess I will have to make a trip to the store.

Answer (score 2):

In a laptop, the screen is connected using an LVDS or eDP interface, and these just transfer a series of pixel for the screen over and over again, not caring about lines.

The data is converted into lines inside the LCD screen. Hence, the problem can only happen in the screen itself.

Artifacts like bright colored horizontal or vertical lines appear when either the flex cable from the LCD screen IC gets bad connection to the LCD glass or when the glass is chipped or cracked outside the visible area. Then the IC can no longer drive specific column and row conductors to the pixels and the pixels remain either lit or dark.

If replacing the screen didn't help, I'd guess that either the new screen was defective or got damaged during the replacement.

Another possibility is that the power supply powering the LCD module, including the LCD IC is not providing stable enough power due to deteriorated capacitors. This could explain some horizontal lines, but these lines wouldn't be solid and would be changing depending on the screen content.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem for a long time then I put the screen in duplicate mood and changed the resolution so the screen would be full size again and this cured the problem

Answer (score 1):

I have a Chromebook laptop which all of a sudden had a thin white dotted line horizontally across the screen. I managed to fix it with the following steps:

1. Gently hold both the left and right side of the screen
2. Tweak it, i.e. twist gently in opposite directions

The dotted line has disappeared for now at least. I guess the screen got knocked a little or I was too rough opening it. It is a thin plastic screen after all.

Answer (score 0):

My Laptop had the same problem. It is I think the problem of the hinges. I used Teflon Tape ( used for connecting pipes in plumbing works, very thin, no-glue, white tape, in kerala plumbers calls it water tape). and wrapped the hinges from inside 5-6 times, as a compesation for wear and tear. And now it is OK.

Comment: Can you clarify where you do this?  Are you talking about wrapping the ribbon cable that passes through the hinge?